# Geting "Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy" in Android 

Tags: android, android-intent, warnings

When I am going from one intent to another intent, I am getting this warning :

"Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy"

and the view stays on the old intent.

the code is :

```
   btnCatalog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   private ProgressDialog myProgressDialog;
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(introPage.this,
      "Please wait...", "Doing Extreme Calculations...", true);
    new Thread() {
     public void run() {
      try{
       fetchAndStoreData();
       Intent toMainPage = new Intent(introPage.this, mainPage.class);
       startActivity(toMainPage);
       sleep(5000);
      } catch (Exception e) { }
      myProgressDialog.dismiss();
     }
    }.start();
   }
  });
```

but when I comment the fetchandStoreData() method, then the intent moves to another intent.
the fetchAndStoreData() method is reading XML reading data from files and also saving data into SQLLite database.

so far I am having no idea why this warning is occurring.

need urgent help

Thanks

Comment: I'm getting the same error.  As far as I can tell, I have the target activity setup correctly and the manifest file contains the activity.  Are there other causes for this?

Comment: @twilbrand If you happen to get this comment, see my answer below. Hopefully you already fixed the bug or don't still have it after so many months :). But if you did find a solution to the problem, why didn't you post your own answer? :-\

Comment: Mine fixed by: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this error when "mainPage" (started intent) was not declared on Manifest file,
try to add :
    <activity android:name=".mainPage" />

Answer (score 4):

Another solution: check the onCreate, onResume, etc. methods of your Activity that is being opened. In my case, I had changed some code so that my onCreate method would call `this.finish();` before the end of the method. I'm guessing some sort of race condition occurs when you do that and every time I opened my Activity I would get the same thing in logcat:

```
W/InputManagerService(  104): Window already focused, 
ignoring focus gain of: 
com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@46399630
```

**Fix the activity that's being opened!** If you need to close the activity immediately after opening, find some other way to do it; maybe via the `runOnUiThread` method, I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

I had a different problem.  I was able to change activities once, but not more than that.  I think it was a combination of using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` when navigating to the second `Activity`, and using `Activity.startActivity` to return to the first application.  When I switched to using `Activity.finish()` to leave the second `Activity` and return to the first, everything started working better.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem yesterday, due to a typo in the activity declaration on androidManifest.xml,but even after fixed the error persisted.

After restarting the Eclipse and the emulator I got this message in the console:once the main activity was launched:

"emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentred"

and the secondary activity launched w/o problems.

Answer (score 0):

Some special hidden char or somesuch in the mainifest.xml. Pasted from another manifest.xml:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

After the problem, deleted and typed in manually. Then clean, build. And works. Fun.